# 1 raiting subtraction from total weighted rating

Tags: php, rating, weighted-average

This is a 10 star rating.

I have a weighted rating of 8.1 made from 25 users ratings.
I want to delete 1 user rating (7.5) that is invalid, how i do direct calculation on this? I don't want to recalculate all 24 ratings that are left.

I tough of this (8.1+7.5)/2 but it doesn't give me the right answer

Any others ideas of subtraction from a weighted rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you calculate an average, the formula is :

(rate1 + rate2 + ... + rateN) / number of rates.

So, we have this equation where x is the addition of all rates exept the one you want to substract :

(x + 7.5) / 25 = 8.1

x + 7.5 = 8.1 * 25

x = 8.1 * 25 - 7.5

x = 195

So the answer is 195 / 24 = 8.125

Based on previous, the formula is :

(average * total votes - rate to remove) / total votes - 1

Comment: Yes this works, but i only have the average rating, the number of ratings, and the rating i want to remove, i don't have the sum of all total ratings

Comment: That is x. In this case 195.

Comment: Thanks, i figure it out too ^_^